# How can I add paging to user controls?

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, paging

I need to page my user controls--groups of 8 or 10 should look nice. Currently, they're in a placeholder:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="ProfileContainer" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

And the placeholder is populated like this:

```
var model = //LINQ to Entities query

foreach(var profile in model) {
    Controls_Profile profile = (Controls_Profile)Page.LoadControl("~/Controls/Profile.ascx");

    profile.Name = model.Name;
    //more properties
    ProfileContainer.Controls.Add(profile);
}
```

How can I page the results in the event I have hundreds of profiles? Most posts I find are related to creating a custom paging control that just pages a table.

I thought about creating a counter that would prepend the first control with `<div id="Group1">`. After 8 or 10 controls, append `</div>`. I could use jQuery to insert previous/next links and control their flow based on the group number. But, how do I do `Response.Write("<div id="groupx">");` in the middle of the loop as the controls are being added? How would that even work?

Comment: You could create a function that returns a DataTable populated with your custom controls and set this as the datasource of a GridView.  This would allow you to use the paging functions of the GridView.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding my comment:

```
public DataTable getControls()
{
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     //Code to populate table
    return dt;
}
```

And:

```
<asp:GridView ID="YourGridView" AllowPaging="true" DataSource='<%# getControls() %>'></asp:GridView>
```

I fear that your datasource has to have an enumerable interface of some kind in order for paging to work though.

If this fails, I suggest you read up on common paging techniques and implement something manual. Not as hard as you think.

Comment: How can I make this collection enumerable?